# In Django REST framework, how do I call my serializer's validate method and also validate the required fields are submitted?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using Python 3.9 with the Django REST framework (v 3.12.2).  In a view, I validate that the object fields were submitted properly like so ...

```
@api_view(('POST',))
def save_to_sheet_from_form(request):
    valid_ser = ValidateNewCoopSerializer(data=request.data)
    if valid_ser.is_valid():
        ... do valid actions ...
        return Response(post_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(valid_ser.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializer is set up like below ...

```
class ValidateNewCoopSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # Set all fields as not required and allow_blank=true, so we can combine all validation into one step
    id=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    coop_name=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    street=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    address_public=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    city=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    state=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    zip=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    county=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    country=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    websites=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    contact_name=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    contact_name_public=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    contact_email=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    contact_email_public=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    contact_phone=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    contact_phone_public=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    entity_types=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    scope=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    tags=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    desc_english=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    desc_other=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    req_reason=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Validation of start and end date.
        """
        errors = {}

        # required fields
        required_fields = ['coop_name', 'websites', 'contact_name', 'contact_name_public', 'entity_types', 'req_reason']
        for field in required_fields:
            if not data[field]:
                errors[field] = 'This field is required.'

        # contact info
        contact_email = data['contact_email'] if 'contact_email' in data else None
        contact_phone = data['contact_phone'] if 'contact_phone' in data else None
        if not contact_email and not contact_phone:
            errors['contact'] = 'Either contact phone or contact email is required.'

        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

        return data
```

The issue I had to add these lines into my validate method ...

```
    required_fields = ['coop_name', 'websites', 'contact_name', 'contact_name_public', 'entity_types', 'req_reason']
    for field in required_fields:
        if not data[field]:
            errors[field] = 'This field is required.'
```

I feel is a little sloppy because I could define what is required in the definition of the fields, like so

```
coop_name=serializers.CharField()
```

But if I do that, then it seems like the serializer's "validate" method doesn't get called, and specifically this logic

```
    contact_email = data['contact_email'] if 'contact_email' in data else None
    contact_phone = data['contact_phone'] if 'contact_phone' in data else None
    if not contact_email and not contact_phone:
        errors['contact'] = 'Either contact phone or contact email is required.'
```

Is there any way to define required fields and also get my serializer's validate method to be called?

Comment: You might need to call `super().validate(data)` first, if you don't want to have to reimplement the default checks.

Comment: I tried adding that to the validate method and also changing a field to be required (e.g. 'coop_name=serializers.CharField()'), but doing this and submitting a form with a "coop_name" field just results in a bad request and the "validate" method is never called.

Comment: I don't think the order of validation is documented, but looking at the [`source`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L421-L422), field validations come first (the handling of `required=True`) and raise as soon as a validation error is found. In that case `validate` will not be called. Since it seems your validation depends on multiple fields, i think defining those fields as `required=False` and handling it in `validate` should be ok

Answer (score 0):

I think when using serializers.Serializer you will have to explicitly define required=True if its required else it will always required=False by default.

```
coop_name = serializers.CharField() # Default required=False
```

Also try adding

```
def validate(self, data):
    validated_data = super().validate(data)

    # Other validation here
    ...

    return validated_data
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not true.  It's required by default.  I had to set "allow_blank=True, required=False" to explicitly turn off validation.  Also, I gave your suggestion a try (per my comment to the other poster), but sadly didn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was required false by default. Thanks. Maybe there are other methods.